# Parsing XML data with multiple children in TCL tDOM

Tags: xml, xpath, tcl, tdom

My XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<msg>
    <MessageError>
        <BookingID>123</BookingID>
        <Error>Invalid patient name</Error>
        <Error>PATIENT NOT FOUND</Error>
        <Message>Incoming MESSAGE DATA 1</Message>
    </MessageError>
    <MessageError>
        <BookingID>456</BookingID>
        <Error>Undefined patient account number.</Error>
        <Error>Undefined Account Number</Error>
        <Message>Incoming MESSAGE DATA 2</Message>
    </MessageError>
    <MessageError>
        <BookingID>789</BookingID>
        <Error>DOB invalid</Error>
        <Message>Incoming MESSAGE DATA 3</Message>
    </MessageError>
</msg>
</root>
```

My tcl Script:

```
        set dom [dom parse $msg]
        set root [$dom documentElement]         

        set MessageError [$root selectNodes "/root/msg/MessageError" ]
        foreach node $MessageError {
            set Error [$root selectNodes {/root/msg/MessageError/Error} ]
            #set bookingid [$MessageError text]
            #echo "BookingIDXML - $bookingid"
            #set message [$MessageError text]
            #echo "MessageXML - $message"

            foreach errornode $Error {
                set error [$errornode text]
                echo "ErrorXML - $error"
            }
        }
```

My output:

```
ErrorXML - Invalid patient name
ErrorXML - PATIENT NOT FOUND
ErrorXML - Undefined patient account number.
ErrorXML - Undefined Account Number
ErrorXML - DOB invalid
ErrorXML - Invalid patient name
ErrorXML - PATIENT NOT FOUND
ErrorXML - Undefined patient account number.
ErrorXML - Undefined Account Number
ErrorXML - DOB invalid
ErrorXML - Invalid patient name
ErrorXML - PATIENT NOT FOUND
ErrorXML - Undefined patient account number.
ErrorXML - Undefined Account Number
ErrorXML - DOB invalid
```

There is lack of documentation in the internet with this powerful tool. How do I get an output of? The commented '#' sections of my code doesn't work.

```
BookingIDXML - 123
ErrorXML - Invalid patient name
MessageXML - Incoming MESSAGE DATA 1

BookingIDXML - 123
ErrorXML - PATIENT NOT FOUND
MessageXML - Incoming MESSAGE DATA 1

BookingIDXML - 456
ErrorXML - Undefined patient account number.
MessageXML - Incoming MESSAGE DATA 2

BookingIDXML - 465
ErrorXML - Undefined Account Number
MessageXML - Incoming MESSAGE DATA 2

BookingIDXML - 789
ErrorXML - DOB invalid
MessageXML - Incoming MESSAGE DATA 3
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `selectNodes` method uses XPath (which is *very well* documented) to find the results to return, with the context node being the object on which you invoke the method. Thus, to find the `Error` nodes for a particular `MessageError`, you have to start at the right point. In particular, you probably want the code to do something like this:

```tcl
foreach messageError [$root selectNodes "/root/msg/MessageError"] {
    # Print some general info (to separate error groups)
    set bookingID [lindex [$messageError selectNodes "BookingID"] 0]
    puts "ID: [$bookingID text]"
    set message [lindex [$messageError selectNodes "Message"] 0]
    puts "Message: [$message text]"
    # Print the errors
    foreach error [$messageError selectNodes "Error"] {
        puts "Error: [$error text]"
    }
}
```

If you prefer, you could use `./Error` instead of `Error` as the XPath search term; the effect would be the same but it looks a bit more like a path. What you shouldn't do is start over the search from the root of the document (as `/root/msg/MessageError/Error` would do) because then you find everything that matches that path, and not just the bits that are within the current sub-context. (Think of the sub-context a bit like the current directory in a filesystem, and the elements as being a little bit like directories; it's a partial analogy — DOM trees *aren't* directories — but it's still a bit analogous.)

Comment: Thank you so much Donal. I'm a total novice with tDOM and XML parsing. Your explanation is very detailed. I understand now and see my mistake. Its a bit scary that your code WORKED on the 1st go. I'm going to read up on XPath.

Comment: @user I've used tDOM and XPath a few times; that pattern (using `foreach` to go over the list of nodes found) is so much easier than clawing over the DOM tree manually. (That's also true in _every single language that uses the DOM_. Seriously, if you're working with DOM then learn at least the basic parts of XPath. I'm glad I did!)

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference the `$errornode` DOM nodes in your code, e.g.:

```
        foreach errornode $Error {
            set bookingid [[$errornode selectNodes "../BookingID"] text]
            set error [$errornode text]
            set message [[$errornode selectNodes "../Message"] text]
            puts "BookingIDXML - $bookingid"
            puts "ErrorXML - $error"
            puts "MessageXML - $message"
            puts ""
        }
```

But be aware: The `selectNodes` method will return a list when more than one node matches the query (e.g. `$errornode selectNodes "../Message"`). If that's the case you have to use the `text` method with each single list element.